Excel, VBA, Chart, ListObject filtered, Horizontal line
Using VBA I am generating a chart connected to table object data. I would like to add a horizontal line tp this chart - but without adding an additional column to the table with constant values. I would like to add it from the VBA code, but in such a way that it automatically changes its range when changing the filtering in the table.
If my table starts with 20 rows, and after applying the filter, 10 rows remain, I would like the line to also be reduced to 10. Is it possible?
For now this is my code:
    Dim lineValues() As Double        
    ReDim lineValues(1 To lastRow)
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        lineValues(i) = 0.8
    Next i
    
    With .SeriesCollection.newSeries
        .Values = lineValues ' how to attach here some kind dynamic range ?
        .XValues = categoriesRange ' range with categories: categoriesRange = t.ListColumns(categoryCol).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlVisible)            
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .AxisGroup = xlSecondary
    End With




You need lineValues to have as many values as the visible rows rather than all the rows
This code worked for me; I have a Sheet "Sheet1" with a table "Table1" in it
Sub makechart()
Dim t As ListObject
Dim vis As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim ch As Chart
Set t = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").ListObjects("table1")
Set vis = t.ListColumns("Value").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'
Dim linevalues() As Double
ReDim linevalues(1 To vis.Count)
For i = LBound(linevalues) To UBound(linevalues)
    linevalues(i) = 50
Next i
'
Set ch = ThisWorkbook.Charts.Add2()
ch.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

ch.SetSourceData t.DataBodyRange

With ch.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
 .Values = linevalues
 .XValues = vis
 .ChartType = xlLine
End With
End Sub

If I filter my Table1 and re-run the macro I get a chart with the line spanning just the selected columns. For example I started with 20 rows and filtered out the ones < 30.


you're 100% right, except my point is that I don't want to run the macro again. I want to define this series so that it automatically adapts to the filtered data.

OK I understand now. My guess is that this is not possible but let me have a think about it.
